# Get my DateTime with Unix timestamp and timezone in Swift iOS

Tags: swift, rest, timezone, unix-timestamp

I want to get the current datetime of a certain time zone, how does this page: https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1562797726&tz=America%2FLos_Angeles
in which I enter Unix timestamp and Horus zone to get datetime. But I need an API Rest similar to this page to get datetime.

I tried using this API https://unixtime.co.za/ but it is deprecated and I have not found anything similar.
This is what I need to send to the service:

```
POST 
{"UnixTimeStamp": "1589772280","Timezone": "+3"}
Response:
{"Datetime": "2020-05-18T06:24:40+03:00"}

POST 
{"UnixTimeStamp": "1589772280","Timezone": "+3"}

Response:
{"Datetime": "2020-05-18T06:24:40+03:00"}
```

Comment: Why do you need a REST API for this? Why can't you use `Date` and `DateFormatter`?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I need the user can not modify the datetime and it is determined by unix timestamp and the timezone as this page does: https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1562797726&tz=America%2FLos_Angeles

Answer (score 0):

//Hi, you test this code.

let dateString = format.string(from: currentDate)

```
    print("53.- dateString: \(dateString)") //2019-07-11T23:45:47+0800
    // 1) Set TimeZone's seconds from GMT. Since I am in Mexico_City this will be: 60*60*5 (18000)

    let timZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Mexico_City")!


    let timezoneOffset =  timZone.secondsFromGMT()
    print(TimeZone.current)// Asia/Hong_Kong (current)
    print("57timezoneOffset: \(timezoneOffset)")

    // 2) Get the current date (GMT) in seconds since 1970. Epoch datetime.
    let epochDate = currentDate.timeIntervalSince1970
    print("60.- epochDate: \(epochDate)")

    let timezoneEpochOffset = (epochDate + Double(timezoneOffset))
    print("66.- timezoneEpochOffset: \(timezoneEpochOffset)") //1562859947.513479

    let timeZoneOffsetDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timezoneEpochOffset)
    print("69.- timeZoneOffsetDate: \(timeZoneOffsetDate)") //2019-07-11 10:45:47 +0000
```

Comment: this works when the user has not modified the automatic time even though it is in a different time zone, but when the user modifies the time, he does not return the hour hour with respect to the time zone.How can I get the correct unix time stamp even if the user advances the clock by n hours?